# regex for amount - fails if have a blank space

Tags: c#, regex

I have some issues with validating the amount within a given string. The problem is, sometimes I have a space in the amount, and sometimes I have a comma instead the dot

I need to parse e.g:

```
1,345.67
1 345.67
123
123.45
12,34
```

but as you can see here https://regex101.com/r/mARXnw/2 it fails in some cases. The currency sign `PLN` is not always presented. Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: So you don't want dates to be matched?

Comment: no, I need to retrieve only the amounts - in the given example I should retrieve 45,99

Comment: Why `801 044 944` couldn't be a valid amount?

Comment: I don't need to retrieve such a big amounts

Comment: So please clearly specify rules. Currently it's not obvious what you desire. What amounts do you consider as big amounts?

Comment: the maximum amounts can be up to 10k

Comment: Please tag your question with a language or a tool and state whether you want to do it in a single regex or a programming language features can be involved.

Comment: You need to escape the `.` in `(,|[ ]|.)`, like `(,|[ ]|\.)`, otherwise it means "any character"... And you can make it shorter: `([, .])`

Comment: I tried to make a regex fully addressing your requirements but it matches `801` in `801 044 944` which is following a valid amount but not desired. This means there is no good way to filter out unwanted matches since you have some amounts in the same pattern you don't like.

Comment: Are there some characters that *always* surround the amount like `PLN`? If this is the case, you can tell parser engine to look out for them.